# How to process an InputStream of tar.gz file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `inputstream` of a tar.gz file. I am looking for a way to process them in Spark. Is there a way I can give it to `sc.textfile()`, so that it can do the extract/uncompress by itself?

I am confused in choosing the right way to handle the input stream.

Can I use the `hadoopfile()` method of `SparkContext`?

Any help would be appreciated.